# How to transfer data from parallel arrays into a textbox?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to write a program that splits data from a text file into parallel arrays and then writes the content of each array in a textbox. The text file is something like this:

Title1, Genre1, Director1,
Title2, Genre2, Director2,
Title3, Genre3, Director3,

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim sr As New StreamReader("MovieData.txt")
Dim movieTitles(9), genre(9), directors(9), itemsRead() As String
Dim i As Integer = 0

Do Until sr.Peek = -1

    itemsRead = sr.ReadLine.Split(",")

    movieTitles(i) = itemsRead(0)
    genre(i) = itemsRead(1)
    directors(i) = itemsRead(2)

    TextBox1.Text = movieTitles(i).PadRight(20) & genre(i).PadRight(20) & directors(i)

    i += 1

Loop

sr.Dispose()

  End Sub  
  End Class
```

When I click on the button, the textbox shows only:

`Title3 Genre3 Director3`

How can I fix this?

Comment: When you set `TextBox1.Text = something`. you remove the previous text. Use `TextBox.AppendText()` instead, adding `Environment.Newline` to the string you add.

Comment: Also, possibly, use `List(Of String)` instead of arrays. You don't need to know the number of lines in your file, you can just add items to the List when needed. See also, [File.ReadAllLines()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines), it may help here. It returns an array of strings  if you're more confortable with it (or a List, if you want it to). It reads all the lines of text in a file in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your data to line up nicely, use a DataGridView. The extra functionality of a StreamReader is not necessary when you only need to pull data from a text file.

Now that classes and there properties are so easy you really don't need parallel arrays.
I added a custom constructor to the class so you can create a new instance and set all the properties in one line.

The list of Movie can be used as a data source for the grid. No need to set up columns.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Movies As New List(Of Movie)
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("MovieData.txt")
    For Each line In lines
        Dim MovieProperties = line.Split(","c)
        Dim M As New Movie(MovieProperties(0).Trim, MovieProperties(1).Trim, MovieProperties(2).Trim)
        Movies.Add(M)
    Next
    DataGridView1.DataSource = Movies
End Sub

Public Class Movie
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property Genre As String
    Public Property Director As String
    Public Sub New(T As String, G As String, D As String)
        Title = T
        Genre = G
        Director = D
    End Sub
End Class
```

**EDIT** as per OP comment

```
'**EDIT** Move the declaration of Movies to Form level
Private Movies As New List(Of Movie)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    '**EDIT** Remove local declaration of Movies
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("MovieData.txt")
    For Each line In lines
        Dim MovieProperties = line.Split(","c)
        Dim M As New Movie(MovieProperties(0).Trim, MovieProperties(1).Trim, MovieProperties(2).Trim)
        Movies.Add(M)
    Next
    DataGridView1.DataSource = Movies
    'To return the movies by Director, I strongly suggest you fill a list box with the
    'director names so spelling errors won't frustate users
    ListBox1.DataSource = GetUniqueDirectors()
End Sub

Private Function GetUniqueDirectors() As List(Of String)
    'A bit of Linq using Distinct so we don't get duplicate listing of director names.
    Dim Directors = ((From m In Movies
                      Order By m.Director
                      Select m.Director).Distinct()).ToList
    Return Directors
End Function

Private Function GetMoviesByDirector(sDirector As String) As List(Of String)
    'A little Linq magic to get the movies for selected director
    Dim DirectorsMovies = (From s In Movies
                           Where s.Director = sDirector
                           Order By s.Title
                           Select s.Title).ToList
    Return DirectorsMovies
End Function

Public Class Movie
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property Genre As String
    Public Property Director As String
    Public Sub New(T As String, G As String, D As String)
        Title = T
        Genre = G
        Director = D
    End Sub
End Class

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a Director from the list.")
        Return
    End If
    ListBox2.DataSource = Nothing
    ListBox2.Items.Clear()
    ListBox2.DataSource = GetMoviesByDirector(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
End Sub
```

Comment: I really appreciated your answer, thank you so much!  How can I get access to a single property of a movie? For example: I want the program to write in a textbox all the movies directed by Steven Spielberg (So the property "Director" for those movies is Spielberg). How can I do that?

Comment: Added an edit to my answer. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: You're answer is so complete I wish I could give you multiple positive rating :)  I have to study a lot to understand all the lines of code you've written. I hope I can ask you further question about it. I'm a neophyte and I'm learning vb.net on my own

Comment: @IvanSabatino You can upvote the answer with the up arrow above the zero to the left of the answer. I will answer what I can. It is hard to find vb.net examples because so many are in C#. Try to learn a little C# so you can translate to vb or use an on line converter.

Answer (score 0):

It is done, just replace the code of the TextBox1.Text line like this one:

```
TextBox1.Text += movieTitles(i).PadRight(20) & genre(i).PadRight(20) & directors(i) & vbNewLine
```

I hope this answers your question bro,
^_^

[image]

Comment: Actually, in vb.net the ampersand is the concatenation character. &= would be the only change to the code.